# large figure in latex

Tags: floats

I want to insert a figure in my latex document. I am using the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image.pdf}\\
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Because the figure is large, latex is placing the figure at the end of the document (even after the bibliography!) When I decrease the size of the figure by writing

```
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{image.pdf}
```

then the image is placed in between the text. But this reduces the quality  of the graphs. How can I tell latex to put the figure on a new page but at the same time, not at the end of the document. So page 1 is text, page 2 figure, page 3 text, and so on.

Comment: Did you try using the `subfigure` environment?

Comment: no, never heard of it. can you please give me more details.

Comment: oh, i guess I was not clear, all the subplots are saved into 1 figure. So basically now, I have 1 graph that I want to include.

Comment: similar to this one http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo_04.png. All of these subplots, are saved into 1 image. @Bernard

Comment: This supposes you have 4 figures that you want to group together. If you have  4 figures in 1, you should split it. That said, several packages can manage subfigures: `floatrow`, `subfig` and `subcaption` (the latter from the `caption` bundle). You should take a look at their documentations.

Comment: @po6 A PNG file should never be scaled. The best is to produce it with the required size.

Comment: I want a regular latex document, what should be the size? @egreg

Comment: Did you try using `\centering` instead of `\begin{center} \end{center}`? Did you also try using capital `H` as the figure parameter, i.e. `\begin{figure}[H]`? Sometimes the lowercase `h` doesn't work.